# GetUserManager returns null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I've been trying to implement OAuth, but for some reason I keep getting the following exception:

> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: context

And the problem is with the `Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();`

I created a new project including authentication and keep getting this error. Also tried to create an empty solution, but still same problem..

I do have the following stuff in my startup

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It works when I add this line:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```